# Can't use custom EditText style in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles

I've been looking how to make a custom edit text style in Android and I found some tutorials and even some posts here but I'm having some problems when trying to apply it to my problem. I created a style but my EditText didn't change when I tried to use it

Here is my style:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/corPrimaria</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/corAcentuada</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/divider</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditText</item>
</style>
```

And the Custom Edit Text:

```xml
<style name="CustomEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/costum_textview_border</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/edit_text_tamanho_texto</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/corPrimaria</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:alpha">0.75</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin_edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin_edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin_edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin_edit_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this is not a custom edit text per se, you are just creating a custom style here, you need to apply this style to an edit text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add editTextStyle without `android:`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/corPrimaria</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/corAcentuada</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/divider</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditText</item>
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditText</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create a xml file custom_edittext.xml in /res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle"
   >
    <corners 
        android:radius="4dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#6E6E6E"
        android:centerColor="#6E6E6E"
        android:endColor="#6E6E6E"
        />
    <padding 
        android:top="12dp"
        android:bottom="12dp"
        />
</shape>
```

in your layout xml file

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext" />
```